# running code in new thread vs main thread much slower

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a piece of code

```
static class ReaderRunnable implements Runnable{
  final BufferedReader br;
  final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> edges;
  ReaderRunnable(BufferedReader br, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> edges){
    this.br = br;
    this.edges = edges;
  }
  public void run() {

    while (true) {
      String line = null;
      try {
        line = br.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
      }
      if (line == null) {
        return;
      }
      //some small code that adds the parsed line to a map
    }
  }
} 
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  }
}
```

if I call `new ReaderRunnable(br, edges).run()` in main, the program takes just shy of 8 seconds to run. if I call `pool.submit(new ReaderRunnable(br, edges)).get()` the program takes 19 seconds to run. `Thread t = new Thread(new ReaderRunnable(br, edges)); t.start(); t.join();` also takes 19 seconds

I'm aware that there is no point putting it in a separate thread, however the goal is later to parallelize the code - but not if there is a ~3X slowdown just from using a thread, why is it so slow?

Comment: What happens if your remove that "small code"? How are you measuring the time: in the code, or overall program execution time?

Comment: @user3707125 I'm externally measuring using the /usr/bin/time command. I haven't yet tried removing the small code, however it is what's doing the work so the time would drop to almost nothing - as an addition (I'll edit the question) the file being read is 140MB, maybe 2 million lines

Comment: I suggest you to try some in-code measuring (`long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`...), it may be helpful in localizing the problem's source: you will know if it is a JVM's start-up time, file reading, or file processing.